# How to automatically create space between pasted images in CKEditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5

[This is the current functionality.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxldI.jpg)

[This is the effect I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYuLb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To create a space between pasted images you can [register a post fixer](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-registerPostFixer), go across all root elements and add an empty paragraph between two images that are next to each other.

```js
const model = editor.model;
const doc = editor.model.document;
const root = doc.getRoot();

doc.registerPostFixer( writer => {
    // Iterate from the end to preserve correct positions.
    for ( let i = root.childCount -1 ; i--; i >= 1 ) {
        if ( root.getChild( i ).name === 'image' && root.getChild( i - 1 ).name === 'image' ) {
            const paragraph = writer.createElement( 'paragraph' );
            writer.insert( paragraph, root.getChild( i - 1 ), 'after' );
        }
    }
} );
```

Note that to create an empty paragraph manually after the image you can use <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the image is selected. Similarly to create a paragraph before the image (if it's the first element in document) you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is a temporary solution, you can read more in https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/407.